# Excel insert rows without conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro to insert a specific number of rows. I'm struggling with clearing the format of the inserted cells because the inserted rows currently use the conditional formatting of the row above.

```
Sub RijInsert()
'
' RijInsert Macro
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+Shift+R
'
Dim Rng As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim rRange As Range

Set rRange = Selection

Rng = InputBox("Aantal in te voegen rijen?")
For k = 1 To Rng
    Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
          CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next
End Sub
```

How can I insert rows without using the conditional formatting from the preceding rows?

Comment: `Rows(rRange.Row).formatconditions.delete` but you may have to offset to account for the inserted cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`Rows(rRange.Row).Offset(-1, 0).ClearFormats`

It's similar to the other solutions ;)

Here is the full code:

```
Sub RijInsert()

Dim Rng As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim rRange As Range

Set rRange = Selection

Rng = InputBox("Aantal in te voegen rijen?")
For k = 1 To Rng
    Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
          CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows(rRange.Row).Offset(-1, 0).ClearFormats
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to store a row number of selected row rather Range object (since inserting rows shifts the reference). Then you can just clear the formatting:

```
Sub RijInsert()

    Dim Rng As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim r As Long

    r = Selection.Row + 1

    Rng = InputBox("Aantal in te voegen rijen?")
    For k = 1 To Rng
        Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rows(r).FormatConditions.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```